# Raytraced transparency not showing other transparent materials beneath?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

I've tried and tried to figure out what setting I'm missing, and I'm starting to believe that maybe it just doesn't work. I'm using the internal Blender Render. I have a subtle blend transparency for my eyelashes on this model, and a "wet" transparent sphere around the eyeballs (separate from the eyes). When the lens of the glasses, with raytraced transparency for refraction, are in front of the eyelashes and eyespheres they don't render at all. If I change from raytraced to z-transparency, they render properly, but I don't have that nice refraction to make the lenses look more realistic. Any idea on how to solve this? I'll upload the .blend if requested.

Here's a render of each uploaded to imgur for reference.

[Z-Transparency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAhwL.png):

[image]

[Raytraced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzUz0.png):

[image]

Comment: Is "Receive Transparent" checked under the Shadow properties of the wet eyeball material? It might need to be checked so that a light can shine through the glass.

Comment: Thanks Spencer. I believe it is enabled, but I'm away from my computer at the moment and can't check until I get off work tonight. I tried different combinations of enabling receive transparent with the lenses, eyelashes, and eyeballs and doesn't get the right result. Is there anything else that might be the issue?

Comment: Not that I can think of... I do most of my renders with Cycles which would handle this case correctly.

Comment: My computer isn't the best, so Cycles takes a ridiculously long time to render anything decent compared to Blender Render.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that, if not rendered across the lenses, those details are actually rendered in raytraced mode? any further investigation requires the file (or at least a sample which behaves in the same way)...

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lzz7xm11omc6bcl/Face_Hairadditions_112415.blend?dl=0

There you go. If you don't have a dropbox account, just click "no thanks, continue" or the X when it asks you to sign in. I'm not sure what is a good site to upload .blends to. Hopefully it works, I don't think I packed the textures or whatever I'm supposed to do. Thanks.

Comment: Whoops, I believe that file is with the lenses using Z transparency, because it's the only one I could get to work. You'll need to switch it to raytraced.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the Traceable property on the Eye_transparent material. This allows the material to be evaluated during raytracing calculations and will therefore let the specular highlight on the Eye_transparent geometry be seen through the raytraced glass.

This isn't strictly related to your original question, but I'd also recommend enabling mirror raytracing on your lens material to increase their realism. I recommend setting reflectivity to 1, fresnel to 3.5 and blend to 1.15. Fresnel reflectivity is really important to capture accurately for a realistic render, particularly for glass and water materials. I also think that your skin material could benefit from lowering the subsurface scattering radius a little bit. This is just my two cents and of course for a glass material to look really good it has to have an environment to reflect.

Comment: Oh I absolutely appreciate it. The only thing I'm decent at is modeling so I'll take any tips on rendering, texturing, everything. Thank you, I'll try that when I get home.